# How to write a Python script that reads two excel files and outputs distinct values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to programming and I'd like to know how one would approach a solution to the problem:

A python script that reads two excel files

- Excel1.xlsx (has only 1 column)
- Excel2.xlsx (has only 1 column)

Then the script would get the names of each excel file and create a NEW EXCEL FILE with the names of Excel1.xlsx that ARE NOT IN Excel2.xlsx

Example :

```
Excel1 has {"Bob , Bill , Joe, Sam, Frank"}
Excel2 has {"Bob, Joe, Sam, Frank"}
```

Expected output would be:

```
NewExcelFile {"Bill"}
```

Since I'm new I know how to read files but I don't know how I'd go from here:

```
import pandas as pd

Excel1 = pd.read_excel(Excel1.xlsx)
Excel2 = pd.read_excel(Excel2.xlsx)
```

Comment: You could convert the data to sets (e.g. `set1 = set(Excel1), set2(Excel2)`), and use the set difference to get items from Excel1 not in Excel2: `unique = set1 - set2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code below, it uses library called DeepDiff for the difference

```
import pandas as pd
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

Excel1 = pd.read_excel(Excel1.xlsx, header=None)
Excel2 = pd.read_excel(Excel2.xlsx, header=None)

l1 = Excel1.values.tolist()
l2 = Excel2.values.tolist()

print(DeepDiff(l1, l2))
```

after that you can create a excel file and append with the function result

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've changed just a bit in some parts following your logic and it worked flawlessly!